# Fast String Matching MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a MySQL database (InnoDB) with the table `users` with a `username` column. On a Ruby on Rails website I have a feature that enables users to search for someone by their username. While typing, the website suggests who the user is searching for (typeahead w/ bootstrap). Currently I'm using the query in MySQL, `` SELECT `username` FROM users WHERE `username` LIKE 'the_query%' LIMIT 15; ``

The issue that exists is the speed. The table has roughly 500,000 rows and a query like that seems to take about second which is too slow when generating guesses on the fly. What can I do to increase performance? Something under 100 ms would be suitable. Perhaps there's a better way to do this than using MySQL to handle the search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up adding a `FULLTEXT` index as Keshan mentioned to the username column (previously had just a unique index) which seems to have speed things up 10 fold. The query takes about 90 to 120 ms.

Comment: Yes, because it will find 1/10 of what LIKE will find

Answer (score 0):

- Create index in your user table for fast results ( This ll really
  help to give result faster ).
- Make sure user get results after typing some character ( not only on
  single character search ).

Comment: I failed to mention that I have created an index on the username column. I would like to allow single character searches, but that check could help a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're searching  exclusively from the beginning of the `username` string, matching against the substring might be faster: `` SELECT `username` FROM users WHERE SUBSTRING(`username`, 0, CHAR_LENGTH('the_query'))='the_query'; ``

Comment: I gave it a shot, but it seems to yield the same speed. Also, I corrected that query to ``SUBSTRING(`username`, 1, CHAR_LENGTH...``. Thanks for the help!

Comment: In that case, I'm in agreement with user: an index will be the simplest way to boost speed. I don't have much experience with them, but maybe a [FULLTEXT index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) will help? Otherwise, you might want to create a new, indexed column containing the ASCII code of the first character and search with that criterion first?

Answer (score 0):

Try to Limit the number of matches you get. If it is a search bar, you cannot display thousands of records in the search list. But from the above query, the server sends all the results to the frontend as I guess. And then you may filter the records from that. Apart from that, try this query.

Limit the number of records to 10 ...

SELECT `username` FROM users WHERE `username` LIKE 'the_query%' LIMIT 10;

Comment: Oops. Forgot to mention that I am limiting it to 15. Lowering it to 5 the query still takes ~ 1 second.

Comment: SELECT username FROM users WHERE MATCH (username) AGAINST ('the_query')

Comment: `FULLTEXT` index did the job. Thanks!

Comment: @lvyCode, what's the speed of your query now?

Answer (score 0):

It will be faster if you create an md5 hash from username+password. Because the length is ever 32 chars for each row you can set an index over this field and use very fast search over an indexed field.